# set TextView at the top and ImageView at the bottom of the left screen

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1.0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/main_buttons_light"
                    android:onClick="btnProfileSettingsClick" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
                        android:paddingTop="8.0dip"
                        android:text="@string/activity_main_button_profile_settings"
                        android:textSize="12.0sp"
                        android:color="@color/maintitletext" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile_settings" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

`TextViewis` is in top and `ImageView` is in bottom but image is positioned in right place instead of left. How can i set it one after another and in left site of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<RelativeLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as a parent view of your textView and imageView and set their

layout_alignParentLeft
layout_alignParentRight
layout_alignParentTop
layout_alignParentBottom

properties.

Also if you use RelativeLayout as parent view, you can use

layout_toLeftOf
layout_toRightOf
layout_above
layout_below

properties to add subviews one after another.

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:id="@+id/myText"  
android:text="Click Me" />

<ImageView 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:id="@+id/myImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you give me an example. I try but still not working. Image is always in right position

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep **linear layout**, just have to change the orientation. Add this to the **LinearLayout** xml:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

For it to align on the left, if it's the root layout, just add

```
android:gravity="left"
```

This will make all child aligned left.

Otherwise, if the LinearLayout is a child of another layout add:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Comment: if i change it to vertical works but image is not at the bottom any more.but is left positioned :D

Comment: Then you'll have to go with the solutions using relative layout :P Other possibility would be fill_parent on the LinearLayout, setting weights. But I think the simple solution would be the Relative Layout :) I think the answer above is correct where it uses the RelativeLayout, use that example :) And you should try to use RelativeLayout, instead of LinearLayout, so it better adapts to different screen sizes when deploying your app. This of course varies from situation to situation :) Sometimes Linear is better :P Depends on what you want to do.